# pow2 textures in FBO

Tags: opengl-es, textures, fbo

Non power of two textures are very slow in OpenGL ES 2.0.

But in every "render-to-texture" tutorial I saw, people just take screen size (which is never pow2), and just make texture from it.

Should I render to pow2 texture (with projection matrix correction), or there is some kind of magic with FBO?

Comment: You can create a POT FBO and then use viewport to set the screen dimensions so there is no reason for any matrix correction.

Comment: @MaticOblak I didn't think about viewport. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't buy into the "non power of two textures are very slow" premise in your question. First of all, these kinds of performance characteristics can be highly hardware dependent. So saying that this is true for ES 2.0 in general does not really make sense.

I also doubt that any GPU architectures developed within the last 5 to 10 years would be significantly slower when rendering to NPOT textures. If there's data that shows otherwise, I would be very interested in seeing it.

Unless you have conclusive data that shows POT textures to be faster for your target platform, I would simply use the natural size for your render targets.

If you're really convinced that you want to use POT textures, you can use `glViewport()` to render to part of them, as @MaticOblak also points out in a comment.

There's one slight caveat to the above: ES 2.0 has some limitations on how NPOT textures can be used. According to the standard, they do not support mipmapping, and not all wrap modes. The `GL_OES_texture_npot` extension, which is supported on many devices, gets rid of these limitations.

Comment: Maybe this is not very related to the question. But is it better to recreate each time NPOT texture of SPECIFIC size, or it is better to have bigger POT texture, which will be created `glTexImage2D` only once. I mean, is there a reason to have some kind of texture pool?